# Weird command characters when I press k or j after running `:source $MYVIMRC` / Neovim

Tags: neovim, windows, nvchad

This is what I get:

[image: the characters]

What does it mean and why is it here? I am on Windows11, Neovim.

:verbose map j:

[image: verbose map j]

and k:
[image: verbose map k]

If I am not mistaken, it happens every time I run `:source $MYVIMRC`. Restarting Neovim solves the problem.

Comment: Try `:verbose map j` and likewise for `k`

Comment: Do you still have the behavior? What do you do exactly to reproduce the problem? The mapping are introduced by NvChad I read that if there is no repetition and we are not in the middle of a command (e.g. busy using the `gj` command) then `j` will be translated into `gj`. But this mapping should only be triggered in normal mode and visual mode not in command mode.

Comment: [Please don’t post screenshots of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: The mappings look like they were intended to be `<expr>` mappings but perhaps they didn’t end up that way.

Comment: @Ben you are right about screenshots but for a newbie without [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) and `Verbose` it is not so easy to capture the result of `verbose` in Neovim.

Comment: @samuelnihoul, thank for completing your question. It looks like a bug in `NvChad`. If you manage to reproduce it I suppose you should fill a bug report in `NvChad`.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with the `:so $MYVIMRC` command. I would recommend to enter a ticket NvChad.

Comment: Not with :source? x)

Comment: Agreed it looks like a bug, so I'm inclined to close this for now.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt can we not copy/paste out of the terminal? or redirect the output? Perhaps I'll update my post to include ways to capture various kinds of output in various tools to avoid screenshots.

Comment: @Ben, when using Neovim Qt or gVim you can't copy the output from the screen. You need to redirect or use [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) Verbose. I suppose adding redirection technique will help the OP author.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in Visual mode (you switch to Visual mode with <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>Shift-v</kbd>) if you enter `:` then the command line is populated with:

```
:'<,'>
```

The `'<,'>` is a range from two special marks `<` and '>' that correspond to the begin and the end of the visual selection.

I can't explain the `count || mode(1)[0:1] == "no" ? "j" : "g` it could be the content of your clipboard inserted using <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd>`*`.

The line could have been generated using the sequence: `v:`<kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd>`*` but it is just a guess.

Comment: I suspect a broken mapping